# I don't have access to '/public/assets' using Codeigniter 4 when removing index.php from url using a .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just started using Codeigniter 4 and uploaded the project to a shared hosting. I defined a new sub domain with the local path of */application/public*.

I used the default .htaccess to remove index.php from url and it's working but I don't have access to */public/assets*. How can I fix this?

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Answer (score 1):

In /public/.htaccess , change:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

to

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

In app/Config/App.php:

1. $indexPage = ''; //instead of 'index.php'
2. $baseUrl ='https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/'; //slash at the end was important before, not sure now

After that all files and directories in /public/ are actually accessible through web. You may want to limit that with the .htaccess file or just put only stuff that needs to be public.